# What is the right way to redraw in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using context.clear() and then context.add() to redraw element.
But sometimes element stay in canvas and I get 2 same elements.

It is happen when upper-canvas does not cleared.
(FabricJS creates 2 canvas element: upper-canvas and lower-canvas).

How to fix it without manual clearing upper-canvas?

Comment: you may be using some old fabricjs version that had a bug in wich the selected object would reappear aftare a canvas.clear. On what version are you?

Comment: i think canvas.clear() should work for you, if still having issue u can run canvas.renderAll() just after canvas.clear().

Comment: Thanks, I used 1.7.11. I had updated to 1.7.14 and this problem was gone.